# Power Set Of a Complement of an Infinite Set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In order to find a Power Set of (B \ A), an infinite Set, would you keep finding elements until both sets have one in common?

For example:

$$\begin{align}
A &= \{x \mid x = 2n, n \in \mathbb N\}\\
B &= \{x \mid x = n, n \in \mathbb N\}
\end{align}$$

Could someone provide an example of how this can be done? I understand with Finite Sets, But with Finite Sets it doesn't make as much sense

Comment: This is a little difficult to follow. Maybe there is a typo ? Why do both $x$ and $n$ occur in the definition of the sets? If they are supposed to be equal, then as written, the set $A$ is just the number $0$ and the set $B$ is all of $\mathbb{N}$. Also, not sure what you mean by "keep finding elements until both sets have one in common." Are you sure you're trying to compute a power set and not an intersection?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Sorry about that, that was a typing mistake

Comment: Does $\mathbb N$ contain $0$ or does it start with $1$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes it contains 0

Comment: What do you mean "calculate?" That is the wrong term for writing a set.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've changed that too, I just typed really quick so made a few errors - Is it possible to find the Power Set of B\A?

Comment: @hunter - I have changed it, - Is it possible to find the power set ?

Answer (score 1):

The power set of $B \setminus A$ is the set of subsets of $B \setminus A$. This is the set of subsets of $B$ which don't contain any elements of $A$. It does not matter whether $A$ and $B$ are finite or infinite.

In your example, the power set of $B \setminus A$ is the set whose elements are sets of odd numbers.

Comment: Oh right, but say if the set is infinite, and you have to list out a few of the elements, at what point would you stop? and then find the power set?

Comment: @RandomMath For your example the power set is known, countable, and can be given, e.g. the fourth element (regarding the suggested enumeration) is $\{1,3\}$. A dynamic view of how to construct sets can be found in recursion theory, where one analyzes if something is computable given finite time, memory space and simple instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If
\begin{align}
A &= \{x \mid x = 2n, n \in \mathbb N\} \\
B &= \{x \mid x = n, n \in \mathbb N\} = \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
C &= B \setminus A = \mathbb{N} \setminus A = \{x \mid x = 2n-1, n \in \mathbb N\} \\
D &= 2^C = \{S\in2^\mathbb{N} \mid S \subseteq C \} =\{S\in2^\mathbb{N} \mid S\cap A = \emptyset \}
\end{align}
$C$ is simply the set of all odd natural numbers. $D$ is the set of all subsets of $C$, thus all subsets of positive odd numbers, which is the same as the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that have no element in common with $A$, the set of all even positive numbers (assuming your natural numbers start at $1$, not at $0$).

In case you are looking for an enumeration of the power set:

You could encode each $S$ as a kind of bit vector:

$$
S_i = \phi(i)
$$
with $\phi : \mathbb{N}_0 \to 2^C$ as:
$$
\phi(i) = \phi((d_{m-1}^{(i)}\cdots d_0^{(i)})_2) = \{ 2k+1 \mid d_k^{(i)} = 1 \wedge k \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$

where $(d_{m-1}^{(i)}\cdots d_0^{(i)})_2$ is the binary representation of $i$ with digits $d_k^{(i)} \in \{0,1\}$.

E.g. 
\begin{align}
S_0 &= \phi(0) = \phi((0)_2) = \emptyset \\
S_1 &= \phi(1) = \phi((1)_2) = \{ 1 \} \\
S_2 &= \phi(2) = \phi((10)_2) = \{ 3 \} \\
S_3 &= \phi(3) = \phi((11)_2) = \{ 1, 3 \} \\
S_4 &= \phi(4) = \phi((100)_2) = \{ 5 \} \\
S_5 &= \phi(5) = \phi((101)_2) = \{ 1, 5 \} \\
S_6 &= \phi(6) = \phi((110)_2) = \{ 3, 5 \} \\
S_7 &= \phi(7) = \phi((111)_2) = \{ 1, 3, 5 \} \\
\vdots
\end{align}